# How to load GraphQL query file and call GraphQL API in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-graphql

I have a spring boot microservice which uses Netflix DGS GraphQL framework which calls multiple backends/micro services. Most of the backend services are graphQL. For my orchestration I need to load all the service GraphQL queries and use them.

Is there any elegant way to load the GraphQL queries or .graphql files? Currently loading the files as below.

```
InputStream inputStream = (new ClassPathResource(path)).getInputStream();
var3 = StreamUtils.copyToString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Doing this kind of code in @PostConstruct block of code. Instead of this does spring framework itself can able to resolve the files if we give the path or if we give path can framework load the query in a variable dynamically like bleow.

Expecting below line should load this query string without any custom code. Or can we load all the queries in a config file during startup and use it where ever we need.

```
@Autowired("$graphql/queries/fileQuery.graphql")
private String fileQuery
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, beans should only be created for application components with well-defined types. Resolving query files contents and injecting those as `String` in your application looks like an anti-pattern to me.

Here you should instead use the built-in feature for this: drop all your `.graphql` query files in `src/main/resources/graphql-documents` and let the GraphQL client load them for you by their name::

```java
// assuming a 'src/main/resources/graphql-documents/projectReleases.graphql' file
Mono<Project> projectMono = graphQlClient.documentName("projectReleases") 
        .variable("slug", "spring-framework") 
        .retrieve()
        .toEntity(Project.class);
```

Check out the [Spring for GraphQL client reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/reference/client.html#client.requests.document-source) for more.

Comment: Reason for loading it startup is to avoid reading it every time(per request) during runtime as it add little bit of overhead to over all performance. Also we are using spring boot with DGS framework so we don't have liberty of using graphQlClient.

Comment: Btw where I can find spring specific rules and good practices any documentation link would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: If you're using DGS (which wasn't clear from your question), then type safe queries are really the preferred way: https://netflix.github.io/dgs/advanced/java-client/#type-safe-query-api